# How can I improve my render of a Minecraft map?

Tags: rendering

I am trying to render an image of a Minecraft map I have imported into Blender.
The quality is hideous, please help me fix it.

Render:

[image]

Map:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Could you please elaborate a bit? What steps did you take to import the Minecraft map?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, the light is too intense in your scene. Try to select the Sun Light and adjust it's Strength until you get more acceptable results:

[image]

You may also want to add a bit more light bounces or some ambient light and experiment with Filmic color management:

[image]